# How to export raw data into a text file as columns?

Tags: equation-solving, mathematica-online

I have used NDSolve to find the solution of sixteen coupled first order differential equations. It takes a lot of time to process, and I want to import this data into python for plots.

Comment: Export as a [CSV](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/CSV.html) file.

Comment: Export["filename.csv",yourData]